# Android: TableLayout doesn't show

Tags: java, android, view, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm new to Android app programming.

I'm trying to use a Table Layout to list some notes. Because their number shouldn't be limited, I have to integrate it programically.

I created a new project for test purposes:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TableLayout table;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(MainActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

        table = view.findViewById(R.id.table);
        table.setOrientation(TableLayout.HORIZONTAL);


        TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams paramrow = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        tr.setLayoutParams(paramrow);

        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("Dynamic Button");
        b.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        tr.addView(b);
        table.addView(tr, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }
}
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.chrobin.beung.MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It isn't a duplicate because all answers by now involved using TableRow.LayoutParams instead os LayoutParams.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't inflate another instance of your layout there. Just find the `TableLayout` in the content `View`. That is, `table = findViewById(R.id.table);`.

Comment: @Thunder The OP is notified whenever an answer is posted on their question. You don't have to leave a comment for that.

Comment: @Mike M. inflating is much later thing , if he want to perform any operation on Table , he is using 0dp height and width , thats why its not showing , check xml properly. and he is a beginner so there is no crime to tell him about answer

Comment: @Thunder I wasn't contesting your answer. I was merely giving additional advice. Whatever they do in code to modify that `TableLayout` in the inflated layout is not going to show. Anyway, your comment isn't going to do anything more than the notification they already get from the posted answer, so it's just noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your XML file with this below code , you was using `0dp` as `height` and `width` of `your table` *so it was not working* , i have corrected your code  -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.chrobin.beung.MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It fixed my problem!